# Jenkins pipeline PR polling

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a GITHUB Organization pipeline setup which ‘Discovers pull requests from origin’. This all works fine branches & PRs are discovered & built when the repos are scanned. The problem occurs when polling for changes. The Jenkinsfiles have a section like this

```
triggers {
    pollSCM 'H/2 * * * *'
}
```

The GIT polling log shows that the following command is executed

```
git ls-remote -h git@github.com:org/repo.git # timeout=10
```

This triggers a poll but it appears to only poll for heads using the -h flag which means that any changes to the PR branch are not picked up.

Does anyone know a way round this? as currently we can’t use webhooks so polling seems to be our only option.

Comment: Were you able to figure out something ? I too don't want to create webhooks, jenkins should have automatically created PR webhooks for all repos within github org but doesn't seem to happen.